# How to make custom buttons in fxml with javafx script

Tags: javafx, fxml

I want to know how do you add buttons to a panel in fxml with javafx script because my program doesn't have a static amount of buttons. Is it even posible or has someone another idea?
Thank you
Fire-Phoenix

Answer (score 0):

If your program doesn't have static number of buttons then you can't do it in fxml. There is a workaround of creating a Panel in javafx and creating buttons inside the intialize() of the controller and add buttons to the Panel. This will let you add any number of buttons !